# is it possible to make .htaccess to connect to DB

Tags: mysql, database, .htaccess

is it possible to read the username/password of .htaccess from a database (to allow multiple users)
i need to manage it using apache and database only without having any PHP/perl code level
any idea is highly appreciated.
Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo "
AuthName "SECURE AREA"
AuthType Basic
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthMySQLHost DB_HOST
AuthMySQLDB DB_NAME
AuthMySQLUserTable TABLE_NAME
require valid-user
AuthMySQLUser DB_USER
AuthMySQLPassword DB_PASSWORD
AuthMySQLNameField USERFIELD_IN_TABLE
AuthMySQLPasswordField PASSWORDFIELD_IN_TABLE
AuthMySQLMD5Passwords On " >> .htaccess
```

Comment: Requires mod_auth_mysql, but is a well working solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it is not possible. You could write a script (in an available language) which creates the .htaccess for you.

Querying the database from within a .htaccess is not possible. You could write a mod though ;)

EDIT: I didn't know that there is a mod already :) Sorry.